# Android Studio Kotlin unresolved reference : products

Tags: kotlin, android-studio, graphql

I am using Android Studio Giraffe and mobile buy sdk 16.1.0.when I want to add a query for retrieve first 3 products from shopify it gives unresolved reference : products but all my dependencies and imports are correct should I use something different?

```
    val query = Storefront.query { rootQuery: Storefront.QueryRootQuery ->
        rootQuery.shop { shopQuery: Storefront.ShopQuery ->
            shopQuery
                .name()
                .products(first = 3) { productConnection ->
                    productConnection.edges { productEdge ->
                        productEdge.node { product ->
                            product.title()
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

it gives .products an error.

I check all imports,dependencies,sdk versions etc